# How to use the 'NOT IN' function in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var query2 = (from tc in Entities.TutorCourses
                      join c
                      in Entities.Course
                      on tc.CourseId equals c.Id
                      where tc.CourseId == id
                      select tc.Username).ToList();

var query1 = Entities.User
    .Select(u => u.Role
        .Select(p => p.Name)
        .Contains("Tutor"));
```

I am trying to return all the `Users` from a database that are in `query1` except all those `Users` that are in `query2` as above.

How can I achieve this? I tried using returning `query1` by adding `.Except(query2);` in the end but I am not sure which is the best method to implement a 'NOT IN' function in LINQ

Comment: your `query1` would have `true` and `false` as values, I guess you need `Where` and then `Select`,

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. `query2` is returning a list of strings (what are usernames? are these related to the `User` entity?).  `query1` is a list of `User` objects. How exactly do you want the filter to work?

Comment: It's unclear, but can be inferred. See my anser. @DrewH

Comment: You can add a `!` to the example of `WHERE IN` here: http://www.codeducky.org/sql-queries-in-linq/#where

Answer (score 0):

That 2nd query just looks wrong. Try this:

```
var query2 = (from tc in Entities.TutorCourses
                      join c
                      in Entities.Course
                      on tc.CourseId equals c.Id
                      where tc.CourseId == id
                      select tc.Username).ToList();

var query1 = Entities.User
    .Where(u => 
        query1.Any(un => un != u.Username) &&
        u.Role.Name.Contains("Tutor"))
    .Select(u => u.Role);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this all query are the same type try to you this method

```
Intersect
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Any` to find matches between two lists, then add a `!` to specify that you want the ones that don't match. Here's an example that should work for you:

```
var excludedList = query1.Where(x => !query2.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id));
```

Comment: Or `query2.All(y => y.Id != x.Id)` - it's obviously equivalent, but it reads more natural to me ("all are different" as supposed to "not any that are the same")

Comment: @KonradMorawski In Linq2SQL at least those two does not generate the same SQL (although they give the same result). `!query2.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id)` would be preferable.

Comment: @Magnus oh I didn't know, I mainly use LINQ to objects. Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

How about `query1.Where(c=> !query2.Contains(c));`